# Magnolia using S3 cloud front in freemarker

Tags: amazon-s3, freemarker, magnolia

We have integrated S3 external dam with Magnolia 6.2 and our development is mainly in light modules. When we choose S3 assets in component the URL generated by damfn looks like this https://BUCKET.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/folder/file?xxxxx

We have configured a cloud front for S3 bucket and external dam url is changed. How can we use different URL for S3 assets? Will site definition help here?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To change the url generated by Magnolia, you would need to make and configure your own implementation of `info.magnolia.external.dam.s3.service.AmazonS3Gateway`, or at the very least extend existing `info.magnolia.external.dam.s3.service.AmazonS3GatewayImpl` and override `getPublicUrl()` and `getPresignedUrl()` methods.